My python scraping data is empty not sure what went wrong with my code
My result is empty not sure what went wrong with my code:
Here my code:
#trying to grab data from this site https://www.watsons.com.sg/health/c/2100000?currentPage=1
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


# Setting display options for pandas
pd.options.display.width = 1000
pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000

Creating a User-Agent
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

# Create lists
items = []
prices = []


# Function to scrape a page
def scrape_page(page):
    try:
        url = f'https://www.watsons.com.sg/health/c/2100000?currentPage={page}'
        response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Check for request errors

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        # Find product items
        product_items = soup.find_all('e2-product-tile', class_='ng-star-inserted hasPromotion-2')
        print(soup)

        for item in product_items:
            # Extract product name
            name = item.find('h2', class_='productName').get_text(strip=True)
            items.append(name)

            # Extract product price
            price = item.find('div', class_='formatted-value ng-star-inserted').get_text(strip=True)
            prices.append(price)

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

Scrape the first 5 pages as an example
for page in range(1, 2):
    scrape_page(page)

Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': items, 'Price': prices})

Display the DataFrame
print(df)

#The above is my code

That website is heavily dependent on JavaScript. You'll need to use something like selenium to scrape it

Hi do you have example using selenium? also how you tell this site is heavily dependent on JavaScript can give example thanks

@jjbkd You can print(response.text) and you will see the output html doesn't include the data you need, because the data is dynamically fetched from the server by js. You can try selenium or playwright, which is slower but can solve the problem. However, if you still want to use requests and beautifulsoup, you need to listen to the network and find out how the data is fetched. This requires a further knowledge of web scraping.

hi Happy Egg thanks but I would need the data and store it into excel using pandas I following instruction from site and that the code which i try and error but now seem very difficult to get the result on what the site teach.. :(

U started on the wrong way, all the information u need (Name and price) is initially loaded on the page as json. So we can just take this data from script block.
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'priority': 'u=0, i',
  'referer': 'https://www.watsons.com.sg/health/c/2100000?currentPage=1',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not)A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="127", "Chromium";v="127"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}


def get_info_from_page(page: int) -> list:
    response = requests.get(f"https://www.watsons.com.sg/health/c/2100000?currentPage={page}", headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    products = []
    json_data = json.loads(soup.find('script', class_='structured-data').get_text())
    for product in json_data:
        if product['@type'] == 'Product':
            products.append({'Name': product['name'],
                             'Price': product['offers']['price'],
                             'Lowest price': product['offers']['lowPrice'],
                             'Brand': product['brand']['name'],
                             'SKU': product['sku']})
    return products


df = pd.DataFrame(get_info_from_page(1))
print(df.to_string())

OUTPUT:
    Name   Price  Lowest price                      Brand       SKU
0                                                                                     3ply Surgical Disposable Face Mask Earloop Adult (BFE >99% + PFE >99%) 50s   10.10          8.00                     ASSURE  BP_30368
1                                                                                           Medicated Oil (Effective Relief Dizziness Headache Stuffy Nose) 57ml    6.65          6.65             KWAN LOONG OIL  BP_10117
2                                                                Daily Nutritional Drink Naturally Cholesterol Free Vegetarian with Plant Based Ingredients 850g   46.95         46.95                 DR OATCARE  BP_75204
3                                Crystal Luxe 6500mg Red Snapper Marine Collagen Drink Berries Sachets (Awarded Gold Quality by Monde Selection 2021) 30ml x 20s   86.70         65.02                     DR ORA  BP_48016
4                                                                                                                                         Medicated Oil No.3 3ml    1.30          1.30                      EAGLE  BP_11663
5                                                                                                    Mos-Bye Mosquito Repellent Air Freshener (Lemongrass) 275ml    7.00          7.00                    SAWADAY  BP_38451
6                                                                                                                                           BreatheEasy Patch 5s    7.60          7.60                  SANTECARE  BP_79625
7                                                                                                                                                 Yoko Yoko 82ml    9.20          9.20                    AMMELTZ  BP_17827
8                                                                                                                           Plus Lubricant Eye Drops 0.4ml x 30s   24.20         24.20                    REFRESH  BP_11709
9                                                       Tablets 250mg Clinically Proven FAST Relief Medicinal Charcoal (Treats Diarrhoea and Food Poisoning) 20s    9.05          9.05                ULTRACARBON  BP_10048
10                                                                                       Alcon Systane Ultra HD High Performance Lubricant Eye Drops 0.7ml x 30s   26.00         26.00                      ALCON  BP_63561
11                                                                   50 Billion Probiotics Complex Vegetarian Capsules (Limits Stomach and Digestion Issues) 30s   34.95         24.46               21ST CENTURY  BP_82443
12                                                                                                                                         Ultimate Enzyme 720ml  113.55         94.50                        AFC  BP_64679
13                                                                                          Tablets 400mg (Supporting Healthy Liver Function & Healthy Mood) 30s   87.05         87.05                    HEPTRAL  BP_18066
14                                       Apple Cider Vinegar Fat Burner Juice Sachet (Aids In Weight Loss + Boosts Metabolism + Blocks Carb Absorption)35ml X 7s   26.00         19.50                  SHORTCUTX  BP_51421
15                                                                      Multi Purpose Solution (Extra Comfort, Made In Singapore, Lens Case Included) 360ml X 3s   23.10         16.17                    WATSONS  BP_43042
16                                                                                                                                RheumaSalve Medicated Balm 50g   10.10          9.09                   HERITAGE  BP_14661
17                                              Anti Bacterial Foaming Hand Soap Refill Lychee (99.9% Anti-Bacterial Protection + Gentle On Delicate Skin) 200ml    2.75          2.75                KIREI KIREI  BP_48923
18                                                                                       Mosquito Repellent Patch (12 Hours Protection, Natural Ingredients) 24s    6.90          4.83                    WATSONS  BP_44750
19                                                                                          VapoDrops +Immune Support Lozenges Blackcurrant Menthol 16 Lozengers    7.35          4.92                      VICKS  BP_77193
20                                                                                            Sea Coconut Cough Mixture (Relieves Coughs & Soothes Throat) 177ml    5.90          5.90  AFRICAN SEA-COCONUT BRAND  BP_10554
21                         Joint Sensei Supreme Dietary Supplement Tablet (To Support Cartilage And Bone Integrity, For Joint Neck Shoulder Knee Back Pain) 540s   82.25         64.90                        AFC  BP_82962
22                                                   Vitamin C + Vitamin D3 + Zinc Effervescent Tablets Natural Orange Flavour (For Immune Health) 15s x 3 Tubes   25.30         25.30                    WATSONS  BP_32470
23                                                                                                            Panadol Extend for Muscle & Joint Pain Caplets 18s    9.95          9.95                    PANADOL  BP_13813
24                                                                                                                   MenstruHeat Menstrual Cramp Relief 2 Pieces    4.95          4.95                      BLOOD  BP_88685
25                                                                                                                    Eagle Fresh On Original Citrus Roll On 8ml    3.90          3.50                      EAGLE  BP_37936
26                                                                                                       30 Patch Light Scent (Gentle to Skin + Pain Relief) 20s    7.20          7.20                  SALONPAS®  BP_13155
27                                                                                                                               Watsons Washproof Plasters 100s    4.50          4.50                    WATSONS  BP_93866
28                                                                                                                                 WOODS P/MINT CURE 200ML ADULT   11.45         11.45                      WOODS  BP_84270
29                                                                                                                             Turmeric Concentrated Extract 60s   14.65         10.90                        AFC  BP_31424
30  Diamond Vision Pro 4X Dietary Supplement (Floraglo Lutein 4X Eye Supplement For Dry Eye, Tired Eyes, Blurred Vision, Blue Light Protection, Eye Fatigue) 30s   60.45         60.45                        AFC  BP_62521
31                                                                                                                            Blackmores Buffered C Tablets 200s   65.30         39.18                 BLACKMORES  BP_55774


Many thks Sergry are you able to share with me how and when to use Json ? I mean i do not know how to identity the problem where you can see it through by using Json thks

@jjbkd Hi, I didnt really understand ur question. Did u want to ask how I found this particular JSON or how to work with JSON in general?

Hi afternoon Sergry yes how you found this particular json example if i want to do another data scraping on another site example this site https://www.singaporepools.com.sg/en/product/Pages/4d_results.aspx or  https://www.fairprice.com.sg/

@jjbkd press f12 button in my browser, it open dev tools, go to the Network tab, refresh page and search product name(ctrl + F, in network tab). Then u ll get all queries that contain this value

sorry i still catch no ball on this. I did a F12 and search by product then many result relate to product appear but which one should i look at?

@jjbkd https://ibb.co/KrzXfTZ and u can get data from https://www.singaporepools.com.sg/DataFileArchive/Lottery/Output/fourd_result_top_draws_en.html?v=2024y7m29d11h45m

how did u manage to find this sorry im noob on this

@jjbkd u need to understand how the desired value gets on the page, whether it is static or loaded by another query, to do this we will copy the desired value on the page and find it in the query search(f12 Network). I recently did an article for a friend to understand how it works, translate the article into your language and read it - https://dzen.ru/a/ZqYPzbpeixpGSq5P.

Good morning Sergey thanks for the info cheers

Hi Sergey I have read the link but finding the api part example you did a search on the product name. for a beginner  like me i still not able to read which to grab from after the search as it reflect too many results

@jjbkd I see, we can go to a messenger like telegram where I can answer all ur questions, explain and show u. So as not to spam comments here?

sure thanks Sergey how do i add you ?

Here's how to get the products from the api:
import requests

def get_auth_token():
    headers = {
        'origin': 'https://www.watsons.com.sg',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

    payload = {
        'client_id': 'frontend',
        'client_secret': 'public',
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }

    url = 'https://api.watsons.com.sg/authorizationserver/oauth/token?base_site=wtcsg'
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    data = response.json()
    return f"{data['token_type']} {data['access_token']}"


headers = {
  'authorization': get_auth_token(),
  'queue-target': 'https://www.watsons.com.sg/',
  'queueit-target': 'https://www.watsons.com.sg/',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


params = {
    'fields': 'FULL',
    'query': ':bestSeller:category:2100000',
    'sort': 'bestSeller',
    'brandRedirect': True,
    'ignoreSort': False,
    'lang': 'en',
    'curr': 'SGD',
    'pageSize': 500,
    'currentPage': 0
}


url = 'https://api.watsons.com.sg/api/v2/wtcsg/products/search'
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
products = data.get('products')
#pagination = data.get('pagination')

print(products)


There does not seem to be a limit on pageSize, so you can get as many as needed, or you can use the pagination (currentPage) to get other pages.

Many thanks GTK can you share with me how and when to use API?

@jjbkd using an api is always better than bs4/selenium. As to how to find the api; use devtools to inspect the network traffic and filter for Fetch/XHR.

Hi morning do you have guide on how to do it cos i learning on how to do it . thks

@jjbkd check this guide.

good morning GTK thanks so much i will read up thanks again cheers

Hi GTK I followed the link you provided and visited this site: https://www.watsons.com.sg/skincare/suncare/c/2204000 . I pressed F12 and filtered by the name "BIO ESSENCE," but I'm stuck and unsure what to do next. Could you provide another example with step-by-step instructions thanks

@jjbkd devtools(F12) needs to be open when the request happens, so either scroll to load more elements or reload the page (keep devtools open)

ok noted thks Gtk
